# Can't open MySQL command line client

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to open up a MySQL server on my computer for a bit, but have run into some problems. One of these is not being able to open up the MySQL Command Line Client on Windows. When I open it up, it asks for a password. I put in my password (or any password, get the same error), and it shows an error and instantly closes so I can't see the error.

The error is something like this:

```
Access denied for root@locations
```

I can't read the rest of the error since the window closes the instant I press enter for the password. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if you are on windows. pres win+r to open run in the run window type cmd.
within cmd put the command `mysql -u root -p` then press enter. it will ask for password put the password if any press enter. you will be logged in

Comment: This actually worked, since it isn't giving me access denied anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Thirst of all I had to open cmd as administrator and then go to the bin folder before typing ```mysql```. 

```C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.2\bin\```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are opening it by double-click on the mysql.bat - Do not double click on the .bat file icon. 
Instead open command window. Navigate to the mysql installation bin directory. Then run mysql.bat on the command line. It will stay there.